# How to have Django Admin render foreign key value instead of Object object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

I'm at a bit of a loss on how to correctly reference foreign key values when looking at the Admin page in Django 1.8.

**What I am getting**:

[image: Invoice list]
Note that the foreign key displays correctly in the left column, but not in the right (using for verification), nor does it show when you click into one of the records, which is where I require it to display.

[image: Invoice change list]

**What I want**:

I want the second image to display `4147128` instead of `WorldEaseConsignee object`.

**Code**

*admin.py*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import WorldEaseConsignee, WorldEaseInvoice

class WorldEaseConsigneeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'order_number',
    )

class WorldEaseInvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    @staticmethod
    def get_order_number(obj):
        return obj.order_number.order_number

    list_display = (
        'get_order_number', 'order_number_id'
    )

    search_fields = [
        'order_number__order_number',
    ]

admin.site.register(WorldEaseConsignee, WorldEaseConsigneeAdmin)
admin.site.register(WorldEaseInvoice, WorldEaseInvoiceAdmin)
```

*models.py subset*

```
class WorldEaseInvoice(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'WorldEase Invoice List'
        verbose_name_plural = 'WorldEase Invoice List'
        unique_together = ('order_line', 'order_number')

    order_number = models.ForeignKey(
        WorldEaseConsignee,
        to_field='order_number',
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class WorldEaseConsignee(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'WorldEase Consignee List'
        verbose_name_plural = 'WorldEase Consignee List'

    order_number = models.IntegerField(
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        default=0,
        unique=True,
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.order_number # I've also tried self.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Python 3, you should be defining `__str__` methods instead of `__unicode__`.